# multistage Docker build with dynamically linked program

Tags: docker

I am working on packaging a dynamically linked c program with docker using multi-sage builds but I am missing a library or something:

```
FROM debian:9.5-slim as builder

WORKDIR /openconnect

RUN apt update && apt install -y  \
    build-essential \
    gettext \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libproxy-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libtool \
    vpnc-scripts \
    pkg-config \
    libgnutls28-dev

ADD . .

RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN ./configure \
        --with-vpnc-script=/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script \
        --without-openssl-version-check
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN ldconfig


FROM builder as gatherer

RUN mkdir /gathered
RUN ldd /usr/local/sbin/openconnect | grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' |  xargs -I '{}' sh -c "cp -v --parents {} /gathered"
RUN cp --parents /usr/local/sbin/openconnect /gathered


FROM debian:9-slim
COPY --from=gatherer /gathered /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/sbin/openconnect"]
```

When I run the container is get:

```
/usr/local/sbin/openconnect: error while loading shared libraries: libopenconnect.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have verified that "/usr/local/lib/libopenconnect.so.5" exists in the final image. Also if I skip out on the multistage  then the container runs just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you use the same `debian:9.5-slim` image which you use in the builder stage in the final stage? Currently you use `debian:9-slim`...

Comment: Is the library in the linker path in the run env image?

Comment: why are you using 3 images? is it running on the gatherer image?

Comment: @byrnedo thanks for catching that. No change after using the intended debian:9.5-slim in the final stage

Comment: @gCoh Yes, it works from gatherer just as it does from builder, but gatherer is from builder and is not "clean".   Also does not work if I move the gather steps to builder and copy from builder in the final stage. The middle stage makes no difference.

Comment: @MattSchuchard not sure. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in builder or in the file stage. Is that the linker path?

Comment: Which libraries does `ldd` list? It's possible for an application to open a shared library without being linked to that library.